# Series convergent function series

Tags: convergence-divergence

Are there any conditions for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{x^n}{n^2}}$$

to absolutely converge to some $f(x)?$

If so, what differential equation generates this function?

In general is absolute convergence in series always a consequence of some differential equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you meant $x^2$.

Comment: If you do, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^2/n^2 = x^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}x^2$, so the "function series" is no functions eries at all.

Comment: Assuming $x^n$, $(xS'(x))'=\sum x^n$.

Comment: The series absolutely converges for $|x|\le 1$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: For $|x|<1$ this is the dilogarithm $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm